# Получить реальный IP в Lighttpd за nginx

Tags: nginx, lighttpd

Собственно, стоит nginx, который принимает соединения на `80` порту, а затем прокидывает на lighttpd на `81` порт.

Сайт на php, естественно, видит при этом ip сервера, а не ip юзера. Как сделать, чтобы видел ip юзера.

Comment: В nginx прокидывать ip в заголовке, в лайти брать из этого заголовка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При проксировании прокидывайте реальный IP:

```
location  / {
  proxy_pass               http://localhost:81
  proxy_http_version       1.1;

  proxy_set_header         Host                $host;
  proxy_set_header         X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header         X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header         X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
}
```

Ну и в конфиг **/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf** прописать:

```
extforward.headers = ("X-Real-IP")
extforward.forwarder = ("PROXY_IP" => "trust")
```

Comment: С PROXY_IP почему-то не заработало. Заработало только с ip-адресом сервера вместо "PROXY_IP". Т. е. extforward.forwarder = ("1.2.3.4" => "trust") - где 1.2.3.4 - ip сервера.